# MVC HTML@Beginform + Submitting a form with existing hiddenfield value from Layout view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my share _Layout.cshtml view, I have a hiddenfield which I want to persist a value for use in multiple pages. Now in one of the page, I have to submit a form which requires that particular hiddenfield value. I was thinking all I need is just to pass in the hiddenfield value from my _Layout.cshtml but wasn't sure how to go about assigning it, the below works but I am creating an additional hiddenfield and assign it's value with the hiddenfield value from my _Layout.cshtml.

Is it possible to eliminate the use of the additional hiddenfield?

Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ($('#p1').val($('#playerChoice_1').val()));
</script>

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "LoadThankYou()" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <fieldset >

                <div style="FILTER:" class="fb-grouplabel fb-item fb-100-item-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>
                <div class="fb-input-box editor-field">
                    @* <input id="item7_text_1" class="" name="text7" maxlength="254" placeholder="Enter your name"
                                       autocomplete="off" data-hint="" type="text" />*@
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>               

                <div style="FILTER:" class="fb-grouplabel fb-item fb-100-item-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
                </div>
                <div class="fb-input-box editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
                </div>

                <div style="FILTER:" class="fb-grouplabel fb-item fb-100-item-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact)
                </div>
                <div class="fb-input-box editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact)
                </div>

                <div style="FILTER:" class="fb-grouplabel fb-item fb-100-item-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonalID)
                </div>
                <div class="fb-input-box editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonalID)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonalID)
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" id="p1" name="Choice_1" />

                <div style="MIN-HEIGHT: 1px" id="fb-submit-button-div" class="fb-item-alignment-left fb-footer">
                    @* <input style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(theme/default/images/btn_submit.png)"
                            id="fb-submit-button" class="fb-button-special" type="submit" value="Submit" />*@
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do that on the [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event. So that it will execute after the DOM finished loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
     $('#p1').val($('#playerChoice_1').val());
  });
</script>
```

If you want to avoid the hidden field, and you want this value in all the pages, you may consider storing the Value in **Session variable** one time and access it in your action methods wherever needed.